# Adding shadow to the title of the NavBar

Tags: objective-c, ios

I got a program from a colleague and he is using .xib files to setup his view.
(being a hard core coder, I never used IB myself...)
So he is setting up his ViewControler and he has a NavBar (that I could not find in the .xib file!).

I want to add drop shadows to the title.

If I was making the NavBar, the relative code would be something like:

```
textViewTitle.layer.shadowOpacity = 2.0;
textViewTitle.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0;
textViewTitle.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0, 3.0);
```

and that works fine.
Digging around I found that now I need to use this:

```
NSDictionary *navbarTtlAts = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, 
                             [UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                             [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(2.0, 3.0)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                             nil];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:navbarTtlAts];
```

Although this works, I could not find how to add the shadowOpacity & shadowRadius stuff.

I found that I could add the following in the NSDictionary, but it did not work...

```
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2.0], @"shadowOpacity",
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 3.0], @"shadowRadius",
```

Any ideas?

Comment: please remove all tags except ios and objc. it will draw more attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use these keys for the shadow *color* and *offset*.

```
UITextAttributeTextShadowColor 
UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset
```

There is no way to specify the shadow *radius* as a text attribute.

---

If you really wanted a custom shadow you could create your own `UILabel` and set the shadow like in your first example. Then you would set that label as the `titleView` of your view controllers `UINavigationItem`.

You would have to update the text yourself though (the navigation controller would no longer do it for you automatically).